# Need dependent select option tag PHP validation

Tags: php, mysql

In the below code i have two select tag, second select tag is depend on first select tag:

i need php validation here i don't know how to do that can any one help me:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset='UTF-8' />
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">  
    $(document).ready(function(){

    //let's create arrays
    var chocolates = [
        {display: "---Please Select---", value: "---Please Select---" }, 
        {display: "Dark chocolate", value: "dark-chocolate" }, 
        {display: "Milk chocolate", value: "milk-chocolate" }, 
        {display: "White chocolate", value: "white-chocolate" },
        {display: "Gianduja chocolate", value: "gianduja-chocolate" }];

    var vegetables = [
        {display: "---Please Select---", value: "---Please Select---" },
        {display: "Broccoli", value: "broccoli" }, 
        {display: "Cabbage", value: "cabbage" }, 
        {display: "Carrot", value: "carrot" },
        {display: "Cauliflower", value: "cauliflower" }];

    var icecreams = [
        {display: "---Please Select---", value: "---Please Select---" },
        {display: "Frozen yogurt", value: "frozen-yogurt" }, 
        {display: "Booza", value: "booza" }, 
        {display: "Frozen yogurt", value: "frozen-yogurt" },
        {display: "Ice milk", value: "ice-milk" }];

    //If parent option is changed
    $("#parent_selection").change(function() {
            var parent = $(this).val(); //get option value from parent 

            switch(parent){ //using switch compare selected option and populate child
                  case 'chocolates':
                    list(chocolates);
                    break;
                  case 'vegetables':
                    list(vegetables);
                    break;              
                  case 'icecreams':
                    list(icecreams);
                    break;  
                default: //default child option is blank
                    $("#child_selection").html('');  
                    break;
               }
    });

    //function to populate child select box
    function list(array_list)
    {
        $("#child_selection").html(""); //reset child options
        $(array_list).each(function (i) { //populate child options 
            $("#child_selection").append("<option value=\""+array_list[i].value+"\">"+array_list[i].display+"</option>");
        });
    }

    });
    </script>

    </head>
    <body>  
    <div class="wrapper">
    <form>
    Category : <select name="parent_selection" id="parent_selection">
        <option value="">-- Please Select --</option>
        <option value="chocolates">Chocolates</option>
        <option value="vegetables">Vegetables</option>
        <option value="icecreams">Ice cream</option>
    </select><br><br>
    Sub - Category : <select name="child_selection" id="child_selection">
    </select><br><br>
    <input type= "submit" value="submit">
    </form>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

i need php validation here i don't know how to do that can any one help me Friends

Comment: What validation? Please, explain your problem in more detail.

Comment: @user3164770 validation for select tag in php